# Filter a list Using Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Orgs
{            
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime OrgCreationTime { get; set; }
     public string AppUserId { get; set; }                 
     public virtual ICollection<OrgPersonRelationshipDomain> ManyOrgPersonRelationship { get; set; }
}

public class OrgPersonRelationshipDomain
{
        //public int ID { get; set; }
        public int OrgId { get; set; }
        public virtual OrgDomain Org { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

var orgs = await _context.Org.Where(x => x.Id == request.Id).ToListAsync();

How to filter list where "orgs" should give result with `IsDeleted!= true`?
Result I am getting is only   ManyOrgPersonRelationship  item but I want Orgs properties included in it.
        `

Comment: Why `IsDeleted` is `int`? Looks like it would be better as `bool`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly and after you change the type of `IsDeleted` to `bool`, you could use `_context.Org.Where(x => x.AppUserId == userId && !x.ManyOrgPersonRelationship.IsDeleted)` And you may also add `.Include(x => x. ManyOrgPersonRelationship)` if you want to access that property.

Comment: Is it EF? Have you tried to use `Include` method?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake the IsDeleted was bool.  _context.Org.Where(x => x.AppUserId == userId && !x.ManyOrgPersonRelationship.IsDeleted) was not having isDeleted .as this object was in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var orgs = _context.Org.Where(x => x.AppUserId == userId && x.ManyOrgPersonRelationship.Any(x => x.IsDeleted != false)).ToList();
```